# State not set in useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have a function to get data from local storage and set that local storage value to state but value doesn't set the state

this is my code,

```
 const [mobileNum, setMobilenum] = useState();

 useEffect(() => {
        getDatalocal();
    }, []);

async function getDatalocal() { // get data from local
        try {
            let mobileNumRes = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@number_Token')
            setMobilenum(mobileNumRes) // set mobile number for state
            console.log("mobile num ======================================>>>", mobileNum)

           
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("error in get mobile no", error)
        }
    }
```

I'm calling this function in useEffect, Can anyone tell what I am doing wrong and please help me to solve this

Comment: You need to post all the relevant code, there's no way we can help with no more than you've provided.

Comment: are you using `const [mobileNumRes, setMobilenum] = setState(...)`? if then, refer to my answer.

Comment: I will add other code part also

Comment: Refer to my answer, it is related to the asynchronous method of the useState

Comment: William Wang's answer is correct, state setting is not synchronous the correct value won't be there until the next render.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setMobilenum` is the asynchronous method, so you can't get the updated value of `mobileNum` right after `setMobilenum`. You should get it in the another useEffect with adding a dependency `mobileNum`.

```
const [mobileNum, setMobilenum] = useState();

useEffect(() => {
    getDatalocal();
}, []);

async function getDatalocal() { // get data from local
    try {
        let mobileNumRes = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@number_Token')
        setMobilenum(mobileNumRes)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("error in get mobile no", error)
    }
}

useEffect(() => {
    console.log("mobile num ==============>>>", mobileNum)
}, [mobileNum]);
```

Comment: how can I set a variable in  useEffect array ?

Comment: is the name of the state variable. so in your case, `mobileNum`

Comment: I'm calling the getDatalocal() function inside useEffect so then how can I call a variable inside that function

Comment: as I mentioned in my answer, you can't get the updated `mobileNum`. use another  `useEffect`

Comment: can you put an example ?

Comment: i updated the answer, so second useEffect will be triggered whenever `mobileNum` value is updated. so at first, you can see the empty mobileNum value, and after getDatalocal() is called, you can see the updated mobileNum value.

Comment: for more details, refer to here. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html